# First Hibernate project with annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is my first hibernate project:

[image]

hibernate.cfg:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:33606/myHibernateDatabase</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">2323</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping class="sajjad.htlo.Student_Info"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Student_Information")
public class Student_Info {

private String name;
@Id
private int id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

And this is `MainApp` class to run:

```
public class MainApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student_Info student = new Student_Info();
    student.setId(10);
    student.setName("sajjad");

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(student);
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
    }
 }
```

But i got this exception at run time:

```
org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
    Feb 06, 2015 9:43:58 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
    Feb 06, 2015 9:43:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    Feb 06, 2015 9:43:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
    INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    Feb 06, 2015 9:43:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
    INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    Feb 06, 2015 9:43:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
    INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    Feb 06, 2015 9:43:58 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
    WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
    Feb 06, 2015 9:43:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
    INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
    Feb 06, 2015 9:43:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    Feb 06, 2015 9:43:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:33606/myHibernateDatabase]
    Feb 06, 2015 9:43:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
    Feb 06, 2015 9:43:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
    Feb 06, 2015 9:43:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
    Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
        at sajjad.htlo.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:15)
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:355)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2461)
        at 

com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:305)
    ... 27 more
```

I have installed `MySQL` and its username is `root` and password is `2323`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a typo to me,is your Mysql listening on  port `33606`

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:33606"
```

It should be (default,if you have not changed) `3306`,please verify.

This may be the reason your are getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
```

Comment: I correct it, but now exception says `unknown database myhibernatedatabase`

Comment: Why hibernate not created automatically? since i added `"hbm2ddl.auto">create` in xml file

Comment: then "myhibernatedatabase" must not be your database,try to connect the above with tool like SqlYog,or mysql work bench

Comment: Yes,it seems,but it should create table with this configuration for you.

Comment: hbm2ddl.auto :  creates the schema necessary for your entities, destroying any previous data.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual error is 
**Communications link failure: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.**
please check the below link, may help you.

[Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect` or `Communications link failure` then it means you're unable to connect to DB. It could be because of you may not be using the right driver or your database is not reachable. Here are few steps which can be used to identify the issue. You can refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358) for detail explanation.

> 1. IP address or hostname in JDBC URL is wrong.
> 2. Hostname in JDBC URL is not recognized by local DNS server.
> 3. Port number is missing or wrong in JDBC URL.
> 4. DB server is down.
> 5. DB server doesn't accept TCP/IP connections.
> 6. DB server has run out of connections.
> 7. Something in between Java and DB is blocking connections, e.g. a firewall or proxy.
>
> To solve the one or the other, follow the following advices:
>
> 1. Verify and test them with `ping`.
> 2. Refresh DNS or use IP address in JDBC URL instead.
> 3. Verify it based on `my.cnf` of MySQL DB.
> 4. Start the DB.
> 5. Verify if mysqld is started without the `--skip-networking option`.
> 6. Restart the DB and fix your code accordingly that it closes connections in `finally`.
> 7. Disable firewall and/or configure firewall/proxy to allow/forward the port.